# Rails: rendering a collection after an object in that collection fails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have the following models

**models/user.rb**

```
class User
  has_many :degrees
end
```

**models/degree.rb**

```
class Degree
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Within `Users#show` I want to display the users degrees and provide a form for creating a new one.

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
...

Your current degrees:
<%= render @user.degrees %>

Add a new degree:
<%= form_for Degree.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

...
```

**views/degrees/_degree.html.erb**

```
...
<%= degree.name %>
```

So inside degrees_controller.rb we have

**controllers/degrees_controller.rb**

```
class DegreesController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def create
    degree = current_user.degrees.build(params[:degree])

    if degree.save
      redirect_to # somewhere with a flash message
    else
      render "users#show"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this is in the call to `render @user.degrees` inside `views/users/show.html.erb` after a degree has failed validation. If I submit the form without providing a name, the degree object persists in memory after the `render` method is called, and will render the `views/degrees/_degree.html.erb` partial for the invalid object. This partial calls the `name` method, which throws a Nil error.

I can throw conditionals in the view (i.e., `unless degree.name.nil?`), but this smells to me. If the attributes on the degree object grow, that partial will contain way too much conditional logic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please add source of views/degrees/_degree.html.erb , and full error message

Comment: This is the kind of thing you could use nested attributes and fields_for, have a look into those.

Comment: @Fivell, I added part of the `_degree.html.erb` view to illustrate the problem. @Matt, I thought about looking into nested attributes, but chose not to go that route right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= render @user.degrees.delete_if(&:new_record?) %>
```

This will stop unsaved records being rendered in your partial by removing them from the array of `degrees`.

It would be cleaner to move this into your controller,

```
@user_degrees = current_user.degrees.delete_if(&:new_record?)
```

Then in your view,

```
<%= render @user_degrees %>
```

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks a lot! The only other solution I see is to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the User model, which isn't the route I want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the best_in_place gem. Allows you to do inline editing from a #show page and is much cleaner than submitting to a different controller, cleaning up the collection, etc. Check it out: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Comment: I've used best_in_place in other projects before, but I don't see how this solves the problem. Editing the degree in place, sure, but what about adding a new degree?

Comment: My bad. I was thinking about how best_in_place handles invalid data (simply ignores it) and forgot it's edit-only. Nevertheless, that'd be pretty slick: click on an element, type and hit enter. If it's invalid it just ignores it, otherwise it adds it to the list of degrees.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about integrating best_in_place for existing degrees, and maybe use ajax for new degrees. Thanks!